# Does Youtube Data API Sanitize Results

Tags: youtube, xss, sanitize

I used YouTube Data API a bit. My page does display users input from Google's servers eg video title. Would you be able to get an XSS by putting to code on Youtube and calling in back on my domain.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube does not allow tags to be created so XSS over an API is no worry.
Sorry don't uses YouTube upload that much